# JQuery if class is active if statement

Tags: jquery, ipad

I am working on this at the moment but it's not fully working, it might be the else statements?
Basically, if .grey-square is active then set a value to a hidden input field to 'true', if it's not active/unhidden in the code, set the value to nothing.
I have loads of q's so therefore the long list but I am unsure this is correct?

```
<input type="text" class="answerStored hidden" name="q1" id="q1">

<script>
$(function() {
$('.one').bind('click', function() {
    if($(this).hasClass('grey-square')) {
        $("#q1").attr("value", true);
    }
    else {
        $("#q1").attr("value", '');
    }
});
$('.two').bind('click', function() {
    if($(this).hasClass('grey-square')) {
        $("#q2").attr("value", true);
    }
    else {
        $("#q2").attr("value", '');
    }
});
$('.three').bind('click', function() {
    if($(this).hasClass('grey-square')) {
        $("#q3").attr("value", true);
    }
    else {
        $("#q3").attr("value", '');
    }
});
});
</script>
```

Comment: Please add markup that has elements with class one, two and three

Comment: Showe the  html code full ?

Answer (score 1):

You should rather use .on instead of .bind as ".bind" is just an internal mapping to ".on" and might be removed in further jquery versions. To read / set a value, you should use the ".val(value)" function to set the value properly. And last but not least, you are assigning a "hidden" class to the question, so in the "else" case, you need to either remove the hidden class, or just call ".show()"

Additionally, try to avoid repeating code. Check if you can either make it more general and update your html structure so by clicking the ".one" the javascript can find the according "q1", or if this is not possible, add a function and just call the function"

```
function checkHiddenValue(triggerElement, targetElement) {
    if($(triggerElement).hasClass('grey-square')) {
            $(targetElement).val(true);
        }
        else {
            $(targetElement).val('');
        }
    }
}

$('.one').on('click', function() {
    checkHiddenValue(this, '#q1'));
});
```

Comment: Ah.. Almost Patrick but the 'on' wouldn't work on the iPad, that's why I put bind - this seemed to work strangely. Would you also have .two and .three after the .one, iterating that code again?

Comment: Well if you can't change your structure so that jquery can figure out which fields should be selected, yeah then you need to add it manually. I usually tend to do as less typing work and code replication as possible. So I try to think of ways to either autogenerate my code, or atleast figure out a way to keep it as automated as possible.

Interesting fact the .on does not seem to be added in jquery mobile. However if .bind works, go ahead with it.

Comment: I tried that but it wouldn't work submitting type="hidden" fields, it needs to be type="text". Here's what I used:
function checkHiddenValue(triggerElement, targetElement) {
    if($(triggerElement).hasClass('grey-square')) {
            $(targetElement).val(true);
        }
        else {
            $(targetElement).val('');
        }
    };
$('.one').on('click', function() {
    checkHiddenValue(this, '#q1')});
<input type="hidden" class="answerStored hidden" name="q1" id="q1">
Is there any way in getting the values into a type="text" field instead? Maybe that'll work?

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify this as:

```
<button class='one' data-id="q1">One</button>
<button class='two' data-id="q2">One</button>
<button class='three' data-id="q3">One</button>
......
```

You need to set the `data-*` attributes on the clicked items, the above one is just a demonstration to how to do it.

```
$('.one, .two, .three').on('click', function() {
  var hasGrey = $(this).hasClass('grey-square'),
    target = $(this).data('id');
  $("#" + target).attr("value", hasGrey ? 'true' : '');
});
```

A sample demo:

```js
 $('.one, .two, .three').on('click', function() {
   var hasGrey = $(this).hasClass('grey-square'),
     target = $(this).data('id');
   $("#" + target).attr('value', hasGrey ? 'true' : '');

 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='text' id='q1' name='q1' >
<input type='text' id='q2' name='q2'>
<input type='text' id='q3' name='q3'><br>
<button class='one grey-square' data-id="q1">One</button>
<button class='two grey-square' data-id="q2">Two</button>
<button class='three grey-square' data-id="q3">Three</button>
```

Comment: That wouldn't work as it's a different hidden field id for each question

Comment: @phil_Simmonds how can you say that? ;) If you change the markup as I suggested I'm sure it's definitely work. If possible you can add the markup in the question above.

Comment: Because there are various # targets on the 4th line, like #q1 #q2

Answer (score -2):

You wrote this:

```
$("#q1").attr("value", true);
```

Try this:

```
$("#q1").attr("value", "true");
```